# Keep row locked when exception occurs inside transaction - Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

We are having trouble to keep a transaction running when a exception occurs and also keep rows locked when this happens.

Firs, a bit of code to clarify.

With this query we are performing a `for update skip locked` (JobDao):

```java
    @NotNull
    default Optional<EventEntity> getJobForProcessing(@NotNull final Instant now) {
        final List<EventEntity> events = getUnprocessedEvent(now, PageRequest.of(0, 1));
        if (events.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(events.get(0));
    }

    @NotNull
    @Query("""
            select ee from EventEntity ee
            where ee.processed = false
            order by ee.createdAt""")
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = LockOptions.SKIP_LOCKED + "")})
    Optional<EventEntity> getJobForProcessing(@NotNull final Instant now, @NotNull final Pageable pageable);
```

The following code runs on another thread using @Async (JobTransaction called from scheduler):

```java
    @Transactional
    public void runInTransaction() {
        final Instant now = Now.getInstantUtc();
        final Optional<Job> jobForProcessing = dao.getJobForProcessing(now);
        if (jobForProcessing.isPresent()) {
            final Job job = jobForProcessing.get();
            jobProcessor.processJob(job);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No more jobs, stopping thread %s.".formatted(Thread.currentThread().getName()));
        }
    }
```

The `processJob(job)` method — simplified — is the following (JobProcessor):

```java
    private void processJob(@NotNull final Job job) {
        try {
            worker.execute(job);
            jobService.markJobAsProcessed(job);
        } catch (final Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error to process job: " + job.getId(), throwable);
            jobService.rescheduleJobExecution(job, throwable);
            throw new RuntimeException(throwable);
        }
    }
```

On the above code, the important part is the catch block that calls `jobService.rescheduleJobExecution(...)`.

This is the `rescheduleJobExecution` (JobService):

```java
    public void rescheduleJobExecution(@NotNull final Job job,
                                       @NotNull final Throwable throwable) {
        final var nextRetryAt = backoffCalculator.calculateNextRetryAt(job, now);
        final var stackTraceAsString = Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(throwable);
        final var executionAttempts = job.getExecutionAttempts() + 1;
        final var newJob = job.cloneEntity()
                .withExecutionAttempts(executionAttempts)
                .withErrorLogLastRetry(stackTraceAsString)
                .withNextRetryAt(nextRetryAt)
                .build();
        jobDao.save(newJob);
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that, when one error occurs and we try to reschedule the job, the following is throw: `Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only.`

I understand why this happens, but have not found any way to fix this. What I already tried:

1. Change the `runInTransaction` to `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)`;
2. Add `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the `rescheduleJobExecution` method. This solves the problem but brings a new one: since the outer transaction has already failed, the row is available to other threads to select and in a multithread environment this could lead to race conditions (ie: the job is reselected to execution before the reschedule is done).

So, I'm looking for a solution that enables me to deal with job rescheduling and also that keep jobs safe on a multithread environment. The `getUnprocessedEvent` method is used by many threads and we also like to keep using the `for update skip locked` that postgres provides.

Comment: No idea how you do that in Spring Boot, but a `SAVEPOINT` is the way to recover from an error without ending the transaction.

Comment: You seem to have reinvented the Quartz scheduler. Why not just use [Quartz](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#quartz)?

Comment: In other apps, we use jobrunr to deal with scheduling, but for this application specific we are handling with some legacy code that fires events from database and custom implementation is required.